# Design for a function to skip a step if called multiple times

Tags: design, javascript, functions

Terrible title, but this is the situation I find myself in often and have not found a good design to make it nice. Lets say I'm working with Javascript and I have an object I am working on that needs to persist to a DB when changes are made.

```
obj = {
  users : [
    {425: {name:'test'}},
    {427: {name:'test1'}},
    {450: {name:'test2'}},
  ],
  deleteUser : function(id){
     delete this.users[id];
     //maybe some other code (ui manipulation)
     this.persist();
  },
  deleteAllUsers : function(){
  var me = this;
    var uids = Object.keys(this.users);
    uids.forEach(function(u, i){
      me.deleteUser(i);
    });
    this.persist();
  },
  persist: function(){
    //some ajax call that persists the users array
    console.log('persist');
    return;
  },
};

obj.deleteAllUsers();
```

So right now, when you call `deleteAllUsers` it will persist on each call to `deleteUser`. I want `deleteUser` to skip the persist step since it will be called later in the calling function.

The two solutions I have thought of:

1. Duplicate the code from `deleteUser` into `deleteAllUsers` and only persist at the end. (nope, that's terrible).
2. Define `deleteUser` like `deleteUser(id, persist)`, so we can specifiy in the persist argument if we should call persist or not. This is an ok solution, but I feel it's not ideal.

Is there any design pattern that deals with this? Or has anyone come up with a very clean way to deal with this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For many cases, I just use the flag like your second example :

```
  deleteUser : function(id, isPersist){
     delete this.users[id];
     //maybe some other code (ui manipulation)

     if (isPersist)
         this.persist();
  }

  deleteAllUsers : function(){
  var me = this;
    var uids = Object.keys(this.users);
    uids.forEach(function(u, i){
      me.deleteUser(i, false);
    });

    this.persist();
  }

  persist: function(){
    //some ajax call that persists the users array
    console.log('persist');
    return;
  },
```

Occasionally though, I might have this structure :

```
  deleteSingleUser : function(id){
     me.deleteUser(id);
     this.persist();
  }

  deleteAllUsers : function(){
  var me = this;
    var uids = Object.keys(this.users);
    uids.forEach(function(u, i){
      me.deleteUser(i);
    });
    this.persist();
  }

  deleteUser : function(id){
     delete this.users[id];
     //maybe some other code (ui manipulation)
  }

  persist: function(){
    //some ajax call that persists the users array
    console.log('persist');
    return;
  }
```

(Naming convention could probably be better, to clarify which records persist to db and which only prepare for deletion without persisting. I'm too lazy to think of those now.)

Which I use typically depends on

- If I have any custom code for deleting a Single user that should not run when deleting multiple users. In that case, the 2nd set of code is better.
- If I ever want to delete a single user *without* persisting, such as allowing users to make multiple deletions without saving until they hit a "Save" button. In this case, I would use the first code segment with the `isPersist` flag.
- How many places call `deleteUser`. If I am only calling it from one or two places, I much more likely to use a flag. But if I am doing it in many areas of the application, I am more likely to use the second case to avoid having to type the extra parameter for `isPersist` a lot.

Answer (score 2):

By wrapping the whole thing in an [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression), you can create private variables and functions.  This way, the exposed API can wrap the private functions any which way, and `persist` would only be called when using the public delete:

```
var obj;
(function() {
    function realDelete(id) {
        delete obj.users[id];
        //maybe some other code (ui manipulation)
    }
    obj = {
      users : [
        {425: {name:'test'}},
        {427: {name:'test1'}},
        {450: {name:'test2'}},
      ],
      deleteUser : function(id){
         realDelete(id);
         this.persist();
      },
      deleteAllUsers : function(){
        var uids = Object.keys(this.users);
        uids.forEach(function(u, i){
            realDelete(i);
        });
        this.persist();
      },
      persist: function(){
        //some ajax call that persists the users array
        console.log('persist');
        return;
      },
    };
})();

obj.deleteAllUsers();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the interface to `deleteUser()` and `deleteUsers()` should be similar, so I'm against your second solution.

In this scenario, I'd keep the `deleteUser()` method, and *internally* delegate to a private persistence method. For consistency's sake, I would do the same for `deleteUsers()`. By doing that you're keeping the public interfaces consistent, and the internals consistent too (at the expense of a private method that is shared)

Comment: Any ideas for designing that internal interface? That's what I'm struggling with.